# Slider Management menu doesn't show up

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, slider

I've been doing a **Slider module** (Magento 1.9) and having a problem with the **Slider management menu** in the admin page. It hasn't shown up though I've been trying to fix the adminhtml.xml file. So I truly appreciate if anyone can provide me some good suggestions to fix it.
Here is my **adminhtml.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <nhatbq>
             <children>
                <slider translate="title">
                    <title>Manage Slider</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index translate="title" module="Nhatbq_Slider">
                            <title>Slider</title>
                            <!--Mapped to adminhtmlModulePath/controller/action-->
                            <action>adminhtml/slider/index</action>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </index>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <nhatbq_image translate="title" module="Nhatbq_Slider">
                            <title>Image</title>
                            <!--Mapped to adminhtmlModulePath/controller/action-->
                            <action>adminhtml/image/index</action>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </nhatbq_image>
                    </children>
                </slider>
            </children>
        </nhatbq>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <slider translate="title" module="Nhatbq_Slider">
                                <title>Slider</title>
                            </slider>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try and clear also cache

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu module="Nhatbq_Slider">
        <nhatbq>
             <children>
                <slider translate="title">
                    <title>Manage Slider</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index translate="title" module="Nhatbq_Slider">
                            <title>Slider</title>
                            <!--Mapped to adminhtmlModulePath/controller/action-->
                            <action>adminhtml/slider/index</action>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </index>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <nhatbq_image translate="title" module="Nhatbq_Slider">
                            <title>Image</title>
                            <!--Mapped to adminhtmlModulePath/controller/action-->
                            <action>adminhtml/image/index</action>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </nhatbq_image>
                    </children>
                </slider>
            </children>
        </nhatbq>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <slider translate="title" module="Nhatbq_Slider">
                                <title>Slider</title>
                            </slider>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```